# cocos2d: Warning: File not found: particleTexture.png

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I have only a line to load particle.png, and the texture is embedded in it. 
Sometimes the texture is seen and somethimes it does not appear.
I noticed I get a warning message:

```
cocos2d: Warning: File not found: particleTexture.png
```

My just code to load plist particle is this :

```
CCParticleSystemQuad emitter=[CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"rain.plist"];
```

This is interesting:
Sometimes the texture is seen: sometimes it is not, and instead of the texture I see gradient balls.

Comment: What tool do you use to create the particles? Perhaps the tool doesn't always embed the texture.

Comment: well known tool.
I fixed via renaming texture file names and not integrating into plist solved my problem.

Comment: Hello, how did u solve this issue? I currently got the same problem with kobold2d and not sure how u solve it